# How can I rename a custom Git alias?

Tags: git, alias, rename

I created a bunch of alias shortcuts. I want to rename one of them. For example, let's create alias `al` which will display all the aliases that are already defined in my configuration file:

```
git config --global alias.al '!git config --list | grep ^alias\.'
```

My alias is now saved in the configuration and it looks like this:

```
alias.al=!git config --list | grep ^alias\.
```

I can call it by simply typing in `git al`.

How do I rename this alias? For example, from 'al' to only 'l'? I could of course use:

```
git config --global --unset alias.al
```

And then type:

```
git config --global alias.l '!git config --list | grep ^alias\.'
```

But is there a way to do it in one simple command instead, without using `--unset`?

Answer (score 5):

To directly answer your question, I doubt this can be done in one command.

I'd recommend using your favorite editor and editing the `.gitconfig` file.  Since this is a global alias, it would be in your home directory:

`vim ~/.gitconfig`

You can easily change the aliases in there.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own alias to do it just in one command.

I've created a distinction between global and local aliases:

#### Rename an alias

```
rename-alias = "!f() { [ $# = 3 ] && [ $2 != $3 ] && [ ! -z \"$(git config $1 --get alias.$2)\" ] && [ -z \"$(git config $1 --get alias.$3)\" ] && git config $1 alias.$3 \"$(git config $1 --get alias.$2)\" && git config $1 --unset alias.$2 && return 0 || echo \"Usage: git rename-(local|global)-alias <alias existing name> <new alias name>\nThe alias you are going to rename must exist and new name must not exist.\" >&2 && return 1; };f"
rename-global-alias = "!git rename-alias --global"
rename-local-alias = "!git rename-alias --local"
```

An example of usage:

```
git rename-global-alias existing-alias new-alias
git rename-local-alias existing-alias new-alias
```

Then your `existing-alias` alias has been renamed to `new-alias`.

---

It is available in the following GitHub repository which contains a lot of aliases:

- https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias